# INNER JOIN em 2 tabelas de 2 bases de dados diferentes

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde,

Necessito fazer um INNER JOIN entre 2 tabelas em que cada uma está numa base de dados diferentes, mas no mesmo servidor.

Tenho 1 tabela chamada "definições" e outras chamada "lançamentos_clientes" a coluna com é o "id" que é a chave primária de definições.

Já procurei muito por aqui, mas não encontro uma solução, ou não percebo como funciona.

Tentei isto e não deu:

```
  $sql01= ("SELECT * FROM $db1.definicao INNER JOIN $db2.lancamento_clientes ON $db1.definicao_variaveis.id = $db2.lancamento_clientes.id WHERE definicao_variaveis.id00 = '$id00' AND definicao_variaveis.nivel = '1' AND $id_tabela_base = $id_referencia_base ORDER BY definicao_variaveis.ordem");
while($linha01 = $sql01->fetch_assoc()) {echo $linha01['id'];}
```

Mas não deu qualquer resultados, o que estou a fazer de errado, alguém pode ajudar por favor.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que o usuário utilizado tenha acesso às tabelas, pode ser feito

```sql
SELECT * FROM <DB1>.definicao_variaveis INNER JOIN <DB2>.lancamentos_clientes ON ...
```

Onde DB1 e DB2 são os nomes dos databases.

Comment: Obrigado. Já percebi muito obrigado, pensava que o DB1 e DB2 eram as variaveis de ligação à Base de Dados.